# Slim Framework 3 session

Tags: php, session, slim

Could you please help me,
My code is not saving SESSION between requests.

when i Login, it always returns null in session.

Thank you in advance.

```
$app->get('/session', function($request, $response, $args) {
    $session = new \SlimSession\Helper;

    $reponse["uid"] = $session->uid;
    $reponse["email"] = $session->email;
    $reponse["name"] = $session->name;
    echo json_encode($reponse);
});

$app->post('/connexion', function ($request, $response, $args) {

            $reponse['status'] = "success";
            $reponse['message'] = 'Vous êtes connecté.';
            $reponse['name'] = "wassim boukadida";
            $reponse['uid'] = "123456";
            $reponse['email'] = "test@test.com";
            $reponse['createdAt'] = "date_exmple";

            //session saving
            $session = new \SlimSession\Helper;
            $session->uid = "123456";
            $session->email = "test@test.com";
            $session->name = "wassim boukadida";
    echo json_encode($reponse);

});
```

Comment: What is SlimSession and where does it come from?

Comment: https://github.com/bryanjhv/slim-session

$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\Session());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the session, [`bryanjhv/slim-session`](https://github.com/bryanjhv/slim-session) has already middleware for that, which you just need to add:

```
$app = new \Slim\App;

// add the middleware
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\Session());

// add routes

$app->run();
```

For settings look at the [readme file of `bryanjhv/slim-session`](https://github.com/bryanjhv/slim-session) as this helper is currently in development

Comment: It's already added before routes in index.php, but session is not saved between requests.